# Class Utils.cs in Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls included already in some dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use in a class library project the class **Utils.cs** from **Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls**

ftp://am.net/LIB/TOOLS/Programming/dotNET/IE%20Web%20Controls/src/Util.cs

I have added this class to my project.
I would like to know if there is a reference which I could just add and already contains the functionality of this class, if it is possible where from could I download this DLL?

Comment: The class is internal so even if it's compiled into another assembly you won't be able to use it directly.

Comment: The best you can do is to adapt the class and make the methods public.   However, i'm not sure if you are allowed.